# I have a not working LED driver IC

Tags: led, dc-dc-converter

I'm currently using a boost mode constant current LED driver IC [LM3424](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3424.pdf). I used a MCU to PWM dimming the brightness of the LED, and schematic of LM3424 part is almost the same as it in LM3424 datasheet.[image: LM3424 boost mode schematic]

And this is my detailed schematic(if it is needed...)[image: my LM3424 schematic]

My problem is that two of my assembled PCB board didn't working(I made three of them). The good news from what I measured is that, the problem is not the detailed DC/DC technology, but the power supply of the chip(I think...). Measured with an oscilloscope, I got no readings(zero volt) from LM3424's VCC(pin 16) and VS(pin 11). From the pin description, I got that: [image: pin description]

I also read the block diagram, and got the idea: if the chip is not damaged, it should at least have normal readings on VCC because the 6.9V LDO regulator will not turn off with both VIN and EN present(in my case, I wired them to 9V). [image]

So is my view right? Should I just go for some new LM3424 or my conclusion need more measurement? Any suggestions is appreciated:)

Comment: Why did you add R11 in front of the chip's VIN pin? I'd check the voltages on VIN and EN, preferably on the actual leads in case of soldering problems.

Comment: @DoxyLover The 10 Ohm R11 is recommended by the LM3424 datasheet for noise immunity. I also measured the "true voltage" on LM3424's pin lead. There is 9V presented on both VIN and EN.

Comment: Are you checking with a scope or DMM? I would check with a scope and make sure VIN is not collapsing when the part tries to turn on and triggering some sort of reset. I have seen this sort of problem. Also, double check for a short on VCC :-P

Answer (score 1):

The thermal limit is also an input for enabling the 6.9V LDO in the block diagram. What do you measure at the TREF, TSENSE, TGAIN, and CSH pins? The LM3424 might be trying to thermal limit.

Comment: All of the pin of LM3424 have no readings except VIN, EN, HSP, HSN are 9 volts, and nDIM has a PWM dimming signal from MCU... And the current draw by the LM3424 is only 10mA... I also touch the LM3424 IC, there seems not hot at all:(

Comment: The thermal limit in the block diagram is a fixed (high temperature) limit and not the programmable foldback point set using the TREF, TSENSE, and TGAIN pins. If the part is not hot all, it's unlikely that this is the problem.